# What is the standard way to manage multiple similar inputs in a HTML/PHP form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a single HTML form that allows users to insert or update multiple rows in a database with a single submission. However, I don't know what the "correct" or industry standard way to match input names against certain rows is.

The way I have implemented it currently is to give each a human-readable name, followed by a delimiter (in my case an underscore _ character), followed by the row number or some other unique identifier to tie the several inputs together against one row. Then, in the processing script, I do `$field = explode("_",$name)` against each name, using `$field[0]` to get the name and `$field[1]` to get the unique ID.

However, in my past programming experience I have attempted to keep multiple sets of data like this discrete, instead of tying them together in a single string. I also now know that PHP accepts form names formatted as arrays and converts them into arrays automatically.

What is the industry standard method of handling this situation?

Comment: You lat assumption is right. You want something like id="name []" in each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="myinput[]" value="some value"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="myinput[]" value="second value"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="myinput[]" value="another value"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?
foreach ($_POST["myinput"] as $value) {
    echo "myinput : " . $value . "<br/>";
}
?>
```