# PHP - process data from multiple input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Hey guys i am using this script to make dynamic webform (add new input if needed).

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <table class="dd" width="100%" id="data">
  <tr>
    <td>Vin</td>
    <td width="99%"><input name="vin1" id="vin1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input name="sub" type="submit"  value="Submit values"/>
<input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
</form> 
<?php var_dump ($_POST); ?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td>Vin</td><td width="17%"><input name="vin'+currentItem+'" id="vin'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td></tr>';
   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });
 });

//]]>
</script>
```

It works well and also name each input with number so in my case its : vin1, vin2, vin3...
Problem is i am not sure how to tell PHP to process this data. Because i am using something like:

```
 public function fetchByVinEvidence() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_calculations WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 5";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>#4</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['street']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['city']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['claim_number']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href =\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick = \"document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'\">detail</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $con->errorInfo();
            }

         return $success; 
     }
```

For a single input but how can i edit it for multiple input, i am new in PHP OOP so i am really not sure how to make proper cycle, how to limit everything to not let user to send milion things to database at once and so on. Can you guys help me a bit to edit my PHP script to be able to work with data from multiple form?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193781/what-is-the-standard-way-to-manage-multiple-similar-inputs-in-a-html-php-form/22196560#22196560

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of numbering the input names just append `[]` to the end of `vin`, when submitted php will automatically take all the inputs that have that name and load each value into an array

HTML sample

```
<input name="vin[]" type="text" />
<input name="vin[]" type="text" />
<input name="vin[]" type="text" />
<input name="vin[]" type="text" />
```

PHP

```
public $vin = array();
public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['vin'] ) ) {
          foreach($data['vin'] as $index=>$vin){
                $this->vin[$index] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $vin ) );     
          }
     }
}
//..
$whereQuery = array();
foreach($this->vin as $index=>$vin){
   $whereQuery[] = "vin= :vin".$index;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_calculations WHERE ".implode(" OR ",$whereQuery)." LIMIT 5";
//...
foreach(array_keys($this->vin) as $index){
   $stmt->bindValue( "vin".$index, $this->vin[$index], PDO::PARAM_STR );
}
```

Comment: And how can i check full aray if every part of it exist in database and display different result for each of it?

Comment: @MartinFerko, edited, something like that should work

Comment: Becuase i can do something like $vinArray[1], $vinArray[2] but i dont know how many inputs user use

Comment: you can get the length of an array by using `count()`: `$numInputs = count($vinArray)`

Comment: I am using something like this on start of my class, can you check your code a bit to help it work for me?
  `public $vin = null;
  
  public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
   if( isset( $data['vin'] ) ) $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin'] ) );
  }
  
  public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
  $this->__construct( $params ); 
  }`

http://pastebin.com/J7xQNyDt

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, unfortunately its not working for me :( I paste here all code becuase i am starting to be lost a bit.
http://pastebin.com/f7fPj7BW

It throw me error: http://pastebin.com/rLNetGKa
and :  Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in \class\data.php on line 28

Comment: oops there was a typo should be `$whereQuery[] = "vin= :vin".$index;`

Comment: Cool mate, it works, but i have some small isue, if i dont write anything to input it still throw up some results, i have no idea from where it is it looks like some old catched one but i delete catch and nothing changed, when i press SUBMIT with no input it throw some things
Any idea what it can be? 
p.s. Thumb up for you!

Comment: You will have to do checks for empty values, for instance if all inputs are empty use a completely different sql statement etc

Comment: I will still have to work on it but you helped me a lot, thanks mate :)